# Input grades that will show equivalent average

Tags: php

I'm new in PHP, I would try to input grades of a student that will show its equivalent.

Here's the equivalent of grades:

```
1.00 (96-100); 
1.25 (93-95); 
1.50 (90-92);
1.75 (87-89); 
2.00 (84-86); 
2.25 (81-83); 
2.50 (78-80); 
2.75 (76-77);
3.00 (75); 
5.00 (Below 75);
```

Here's my code:

```
<form method="POST">
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="someid" name="number" 
       maxlength="3" Onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" required />

<?php
   $number='';
   if (!empty($number)) {
        switch (true) {
            case $number>=96&& $number<=100:
                break;
            case $number>=93&& $number<=95:
                break;
            case $number>=90&& $number<=92:
                break;
            case $number>=87&& $number<=89:
                break;
            case $number>=84&& $number<=86:
                break;
            case $number>=81&& $number<=83:
                break;
            case $number>=78&& $number<=80:
                break;
            case $number>=76&& $number<=77:
                break;
            case $number>=75:
                break;
   }

?>
```

My question is how can I input grades for example 90 that will show the equivalent of 90 using PHP?

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: You can't declare number ranges by simply putting (for example) `78 - 80`. With this you're actually doing a subtraction, meaning you're comparing `$avg` to `-2`, which is probably not what you're trying to do.

Comment: It looks like you are mixing up javascript (onKeyPress-event) and PHP. In order for PHP to be able to process the value from your input you have to submit the form and then read the number from `$_POST['someid']`. I think you should brush up on some basics first. You seem to be mixing up server side and client side.